# Creating QuoteLineItem after creating Opportunity Line Item

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem

I have created a webservice to create Opportunity, OpportunityLineItem and related Quote. When I do the same activity in configuration. QuoteLineItem gets created automatically. But when i do that same activity in code. The Opportunity is inserted, followed  by OpportunityLineItem and related Quote**.But QuoteLineItem is not created.**

Am I missing something. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Following is the code used in test class.

```
 Date t = System.Today();
        Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Opp1', StageName ='New', CloseDate = t);
        insert o1;
        Product2 p = new product2(name='unittest');
        p.Family = 'License';
        insert p;
        Id stdPbId = test.getstandardpricebookid();
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = stdPbid, product2id = p.id,unitprice=1.0,isActive=true);
        insert pbe;
        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id,OpportunityId=o1.Id,Quantity=10,TotalPrice=100);
        Quote q1 = new Quote(Name ='q1', OpportunityId = o1.Id,Pricebook2Id = stdPbid );
        insert q1;

        List<QuoteLineItem> qli = new List<QuoteLineItem>([Select id from QuoteLineItem where quoteId =: q1.Id]);
        System.assert(qli.size()>0);
```

Comment: Without looking at the code, it is near impossible to tell what exactly is going wrong. Kindly paste your code here by editing your question.

Comment: Kindly paste only the _minimal essence_ of your code that reproduces the problem using [edit]